# what can be improved in a fuzzy c means algorithm

Tags: python, r, algorithm, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I want to hybridize a classic fuzzy c means algorithm with kernel function in order to perform text classification. At the end I hope to achieve a better accuracy and convergence (to be measured using time taken) after comparing the generic FCM and hybrid FCM. My question is, between the partition matrix, objective function and membership matrix, which is the most logical part to make an improvement on